# Passing parameter from js to django

Tags: javascript, django

I have a function in views.py

```
def time(request): 
    date = Registration.objects.filter(date_visit=date_use)
    time_list=[]
    for a in date:
        time_list.append(date.time_visit)
    return JsonResponse({'time_list':time_list})
```

I want to pass there the date_use parameter from my field in the form.

I calculate the field values ​​like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pole').change('input', function() {
     var val = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

How can I pass val value to date_use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `data` key in JS `ajax` request to pass parameters in both `get` and `post` request.

Note - when submitting forms using Django, you'll need to grab the `csrf token` and set it as `X-CSRFToken` header. You can use the follow code supplied in Django Docs itself, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/).

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
  $('.pole').change('input', function() {
     var datetime = $(this).val();
     var cookie = getCookie('csrftoken')
       $.ajax({
           url: '/your-url/',
           headers: {'X-CSRFToken': cookie},
           type: 'get', // can be 'post' as well or anything else you'd want such as 'put', 'patch', etc'
           data: {'datetime': datetime},
           success: function(e){
             console.log(e)
           },
           error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
           }
       })    
  });
```

views.py

```
def time(request): 
    if request.method == "GET":
        date = Registration.objects.filter(date_visit=date_use)
        # you can get the value from the JS using the `key` in `data` attribute of `ajax request`
        data_from_form = request.GET.get('datetime')

        # if you have multiple inputs coming your way for example if there's a list of inputs you're getting you can use 
        data_from_form = request.GET.getlist('datetime')
        time_list=[]
        for a in date:
            time_list.append(date.time_visit)
        return JsonResponse({'time_list':time_list})
```

Note - You may need to use `ajax request` in multiple pages and copy and pasting the `getCookie` function in every page is very counterproductive. Instead what you can do is paste this code in a new file called `utils.js` and import this file in your `base.html`. Keep in mind that the import positioning for `utils.js`. If you need to use the functions inside it into another script you'll need to import that particular script below `utils.js`

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script src="{% static '/js/utils.js' %}" type='text/javascript'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should see again what is asking the user.

Comment: He asked how to pass values from a `from` using JS to Django view. That's what I have replied with. This is a boilerplate code he can modify it to his use, but the basic `ajax request` idea I have given.

Comment: yep you are right. but keep in mind he is a new user. he may not know how to ask the right way. so if you see code that make sense what he wants.

Comment: in urls.py  `path('time/', views.time)`
and i add in `url: '/your-url/', url: '/time/'` 
Did I do everything right?

Comment: review your code. you should not use X-CSRFToken when you are using the GET method with ajax. :/ he just needs to pass a parameter to time def. date = Registration.objects.filter(date_visit=HERE_GOES_THE_PARAMETER)

Comment: you are just the best teacher)
you probably didn’t quite understand what I needed, but according to the detailed answer given, I figured it out
thanks a lot

Comment: I added the `X-CSRFToken` just in case he tries a POST request in future. @BobWhite